# pascal abc проверка ввода, проблема в цикле

Tags: pascal, while, pascalabc.net

Помогите с проверкой на ввод данных пожалуйста :) Вроде сделал все но есть пару но =\ при проверке все ок а вот с последующими условиями беда =\
Суть в том что мы из 1 цикла переходим во 2 если получилось присвоить... а во 2 после ввода новых данных мы уходим в 1 цикл на проверку опять.
Если даже ввести все правильно (2 изооброжение) то ничего не происходит дальше =\ где-то я в киклах намудрил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
while true do
begin
  integer.TryParse(Buff, Size);
  if (Size = 0) then 
  begin
    write('Введите верное значение: ');
    readln(Buff);
  end
  else
    while true do 
    begin 
      if (Size < 3) or (Size > 100) then 
      begin
        write('Ошибка, введите значение соот. условию: ');
        read(Buff);
        break;
      end
      else 
        break;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что такое "киклы"? А-а-а, "циклы". Одного достаточно.

```
Write('Введите целое число от 3 до 100: ');

while true do
begin
  ReadLn(Buff);
  if not integer.TryParse(Buff, Size) then 
  begin
    Write('Не число. Попробуйте еще раз:');
  end
  else if (Size < 3) or (Size > 100) then
  begin
    Write('Не попали в диапазон. Попробуйте еще раз:');
  end
  else 
    break;
end;
```